# Windows XAML: LineCount in TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, textblock, line-count

I have a Text Block that I write on a Canvas. Since it is on a Canvas, I manually specify x-coord and y-coord.

My problem is, my y-coord is dependent on the LineCount of the wrapping on my TextBlock (due to limited width).

For example, the text "ADD Bananas" is written as:

ADD
Bananas

which has 2 line count.

Depending on the line count, I do something.

Right now, I am using this to determine the TextWidth and then do calculations from there. However, there are still some outliers (ex. instead of supposed to be 3 lines calculated, 2 in actual visual):

```
private double stringWidth(string s, double fontSize)
{
    if(s==" ")
        s = "\u00A0";  //this line wasn't required in silverlight but is now

    TextBlock t = new TextBlock()
    {
        FontSize = fontSize,
        Text = s
    };
    t.Measure(new Size(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue));  //this line wasn't required in silverlight but is now
    return t.ActualWidth;
}
```

Is there a best way to do this in Windows App Xaml?

Comment: do you solve this problem? I have the some question...

Comment: Hi meadlai, I just used the wrapping of TextBlock and specified a certain height and width for the TextBlock.

Comment: thanks... I count the width by a new TextBlock in memory.